# How to get value from the previous function call using default parameter?

Tags: c++, function, static

### How it works

main function will call Square() with an int value, where it will be multiplied by itself and returned to main. However, if no parameters are provided, then the previous int value will be incremented and used. If provided a value of 5, then return 25, then I do not add in a parameter and call the function again, it will return the square of 5+1, so I will get 36, then if the next call has no parameter, i will get square of 7 which is 49.

### Problem

Here I declared static int lastN to take in the n value of the first call. If the next call has no parameters passed in to square(), then unsigned int n will be -1 and lastN, which store the previous value of parameter n (in this case 5), then lastN will automatically be incremented and the square of lastN returned. However, it seems that the static variable is not working, I keep getting 1 with no parameters, I am not very sure n how to get the previous value with static variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int square(unsigned int n=-1)
{
   static int lastN;
    if(n==-1)
    {
        lastN+=1;
        return (lastN)*(lastN);
    }

    lastN=n;
   return n*n;
}

void main () {
  
       cout <<"Value: "<< square(5) << endl;
}
```

Thx so far for the answers. Ok to make things clear, my instructor told me to use -1 for default value so that if no parameters are passed into the function, then default value will definitely not be unsigned int. If not if I use a positive value like 10 as default value, then problems arise when my instructor passes in 10 as parameter to test the code. If I enter 5, lastN will be 5, and the square 25 returned, then for the next call I do not put in any parameters into the function call for int square(),

```
void main () {

       cout <<"Value: "<< square() << endl; //no parameter
}
```

instead of increment the previous value to 6 and returning square of 6, I get

Value: 1

Press any key to continue...

I am starting c++ so I am not very sure on using static variables or any other types like passing variable into function by value or reference

Comment: This doesn't compile because of your `void main`, which should be `int main`. However, even with this fixed and `square()` called afterwards, everything works fine. What compiler do you use, how do you invoke it, and what is actually the code which supposedly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Seems to works as expected: https://ideone.com/R7bvYI

Comment: "I keep getting 1 with no parameters" I suspect an edge case... have you tried calling it with something first?

Comment: You have to initialize the lstN variable the first time: static int lastN = 0;

Comment: your code is working...please show some code snippet of how you are calling the function and which compiler are you using?

Comment: You must be testing some other code than the one you posted.

Comment: @gauravsehgal; Its not working. It invokes UB.

Comment: There is no UB here.  Just the ill-formed "`void main()`", but `square` works as advertised.

Comment: Isn't using an uninitialized variable UB?

Comment: worked correctly in visual studio...static variables are initialized to zero.

Comment: `unsigned int` cannot have values below zero (parameter), and calculated `signed -1*-1 = 1`, so there's that. You have to check your types better. And also, please set `static int lastN = 0` in case that you will not run this in debug mode...